LaTeX \chemfig{} structuring of Diisopropyl sulfate error
In LaTeX i'm attempting to create a chemical structure for Diisopropyl sulfate, it should look the image provided.

However, my chemical configuration looks like:

The code I used to try that is as follows:
\chemfig{*6(-CH_3(-[2]CH_3)-CH(-O-S(=[4]O)(-O-[2]CH_3))(-CH_3) )}

What do I need to do to fix my mistake and ensure that the structure is correct?
EDIT: I have managed to fix the chemfig issue, however one issue that persists is how would I alter it further to get the geometry as shown in image 1?
Script:
\chemfig{*6(CH_3-CH(-[8.5]CH_3)(-O-S(=[4]O)(=[8]O)-O-CH(-[5]CH_3)-[7]CH_3))}



Welcome to TeX.SX!

The code *6(...) is used to create hexagonal rings
Create your molecule by explicitly declaring the bond angles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{H_3C-(-[:60]CH_3)-[:300]O-S(=[2]O)(=[6]O)-O-[:300](-[:240]H_3C)-[0]CH_3}
\end{document}


To use colors change "O" by "{\color{red}O}"

